# How to recognize windows' permissions on a OSX server share

Tags: windows, permissions, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

I have a server running OSX (Mountain Lion), accessed by a Windows 7 box. Investigating a permissions problem from the Win client, I open the permissions dialog on a network share's directory and see this:

[image: Windows permissions]

Authentication on workstations are local, and authentication on server is made by Open Directory. How do I tell who is who?

Answer (score 2):

```
S-1-5-88-         is the NFS base RID
S-1-5-88-1-1029   is User ID 1029
S-1-5-88-2-100    is Group ID 100
S-1-5-88-3-16832  is the access mode (octal 40700)
S-1-5-21-         is the domain, which the client is apparently not a part of.
```

Try joining the windows client to the domain to get the SID for `S-1-5-21` resolved.  The `S-1-5-88` can't be mapped since W7/2008 no longer support NFS user mapping.

Comment: Thanks; If I remember well, since 10.7, OS X Server doesn't offer Windows domain service, so I can't join anything.

Comment: I believe opendirectory supports Kerberos, so you can join with `ksetup`, but you are right... it doesn't look like it supports the RPC command needed to translate SIDs.